# "This can make us think the concepts are related, which in fact they are not."

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subjects

> This can lead inexperienced mathematicians to conclude that these concepts are related, **which in fact they are not**. 
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers).</sub>

I would expect the bold part to instead be "**which, in fact, are not**".

It seems to be the case that the ***which*** does not refer to the **concepts** and it appears to me that there's something omitted. If so, what is omitted here?

I've seen this usage a lot and so I don't doubt about its correctness now and wish to know about its **grammar aspects**.

Comment: I suppose your cited text could be seen as "clumsy", but your attempt to "fix" it just makes things even worse. Better by far to simply replace ***which*** with ***when*** (or perhaps ***but***), then no-one could pick holes in it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "which, in fact, are not" doesn't sound the way the author would want it to sound, but surely it's grammatical. Is the Wikipedia's expression ungrammatical? I want to know the rigorous evaluation of the correctness of it. And wouldn't your 'when' refer to time? There was no time mentioned in the sentence before the relative clause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers' edit works, too: *when* can refer to situations as well as events.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'd never really thought about such usages of ***when*** (or ***while***) before. It's in OED as defn 9b *In adversative sense: While on the other hand, while on the contrary, whereas.* But quite how/why ***when*** and ***while*** lose their "temporal" associations there, and what happens to the "locative" sense of ***whereas***, curremtly escapes me.

Comment: @mathh: I'm guessing you're not a native speaker. So far as I can tell, there's no suggestion of *time* being relevant to my proposed change involving ***when***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it true that the sense which the '_when_' of your edit was used in is exactly the same in which '_while_' is usually used? As in, '_He is huge, while (while on the other hand/while on the contrary) his brother is tiny._'. And I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @StoneyB Is my last reply to FumbleFingers correct?

Comment: Yes, *while* there would have much the same sense as *when* -- both express a contrast.

Comment: @mathh: I can't put my finger on exactly why, but idiomatically we can't replace *while* by *when* in your "tiny brother" example (but we can use *whereas, yet, but*). Perhaps you were right in the first place, and there *is* some element of "temporality" (something to do with *time*) in such usages involving *when*. It's intriguing to me that I can easily accept *when* if I make some apparently trivial changes: *"**You say** he is huge, **when actually he** is tiny"*. In which context it seems to mean something akin to ***but at the same time***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The antecedent of *which* is not the noun *concepts* but the adjective *related*:

```
 ...        in fact they are not related.
 ...        in fact they are not [which]
         ↓  ←  ←  ←  ←  ←  ←  ←  ←  ↵   
 .... which in fact they are not
```

Comment: oh, I understand it now. My mistake was having unconscious thinking that 'which' always refer to nouns.